# Flutter IOS BLE unstable connection when run in background mode

Tags: ios, flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, ios-background-mode

I'm using [flutter_reactive_ble](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_reactive_ble) to connect and read temperature from thermometer device in background mode. My thermometer devices are advertising every 3, 6, 9 or 12 minutes based on the device calculation. But when running there is sometime that my app doesn't get data from device for 1-2 hours or more.

What I tried is connect to the device -> read data -> disconnect -> wait 2 seconds -> reconnect to the device. This will be forever until the user unregister the device from the app. The app will run 1 or several days smoothly as I expected and then it started not receiving data for 1-2 hours and then received data again. Don't know why it happens.
So my expectation is that the app will get data from the device every 3,6,9 or 12 minutes is at least.
Is there anyone have experience on this case?. Or a way to troubleshoot it?
Any comment will help me very much.

Comment: Does the thermometer send the temperature via notify/indicate?  If so, your strategy should be simply to connect and wait for data to be sent via a notification. If the peripheral disconnects, immediately issue another connect and wait for it to be completed.

Comment: Thank for your comment Paulw11. The device doesn't design for sending the temperature via notify. It will advertise every 3,6,9 or 12 minutes. My app need to connect to the device and read its characteristic and disconnect and then wait for the next advertising

Comment: What do you mean "advertise"?  Do you mean that it stops advertising its BLE GATT service and is not connectable?  If so then a pending connect will work for you. If you issue a `connect` for a peripheral that is not currently connectable, then iOS will handle the connection for you and give a delegate callback once the peripheral is connected - refer https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW5

Comment: Do you mean that it stops advertising its BLE GATT service and is not connectable?Yes, exactly. I implemented like what you mentioned @Paulw11. and It worked for several days and then sometime it took 1 - 2 hours or more to get data from the device, I don't know whether it's related to CoreBluetooth and IOS condition or the device wasn't connectable at that time. The device provider is sure that their device works well. Don't know if there is a way that I can troubleshoot it?. My requirement is that the app will get data from the device at least every 12 minutes in good condition.

Comment: It is very important that your app correctly implements core Bluetooth state restoration as described in the document I linked to. This might be trickier in Flutter than in native code. I have an app that connects to a UHF radio in my car. It can go for days between connections (I don't always turn the radio on) and always connects within seconds of the radio being turned on.  It took a bit of work to ensure that I implemented state restoration correctly.

Comment: Yes, I've forked the library and add state restoration already, if my understanding is correct then if my app didn't implement this feature then after being terminated by OS, It won't get data after then. but after 1-2 hours or more my app started getting data again. So It may be that my app was terminated by OS and then restored after 1-2 hours. But the iPhone that I tested my app didn't run any other apps or connect any other BLE device. So I don't know for sure if it is the case. Is it possible that we can detect when our app are terminated or can we force the OS terminate our app?.